# ExtJs - getRow by index of Gridpanel

Tags: extjs

Im using Extjs 4.1 with a gridpanel. Now I want to get a row by id/index to just hide it (not filter).

I tried that (it says there is no method getRow):

`gridpanel.getView().getRow( 0 );`

What is the correct way now?

I know `gridview` has `getRow`, so why cant I use it?

Edit: there seems to be no such method in 4.

Comment: `getRow` doesn't exist, you're probably looking for `getRecord`

Comment: it existed in 3.4. Ill try getRecord

Comment: Now i think about it, `getRecord` will probably return the model instead of the actual row...

Comment: yea how can i select by index (int)?

Comment: Hold on, i'm gonna find out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since ExtJS 4.1.3 no longer returns a `GridView` you have to work around this.

Take a look at:
[Sencha Forum --> Getting gridview row element](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?258071-How-to-get-an-Element-of-a-grid-row-in-Ext-JS-4&p=945574)

In my opinion its a ugly solution, but it's not getting alot of attention..

Comment: Thanks for the help but I wont use that approach any further. I will change my concept now. %?§#!

Comment: who is interested how to get record using ugly solution it is grid.getView().getRecord(grid.getView().getNode(rowIndex))